# custom query in LessQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to fire a custom query at the database through LessQL?

The reason for asking, is that I would like to do a query like this:

> DESCRIBE TableName

(which is a Mysql thing)

So perhaps something like $db->customquery('DESCRIBE mytable');

Answer (score 0):

when you use Lessql you have to provide a PDO instance to the Database constructor, so you can use this PDO object to get the structure of a table (Just like in this [tutorial](http://thisinterestsme.com/get-structure-of-mysql-table-in-php/). You don't need some particular Lessql method for doing that. Hope that answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the code you can see a method called query..... Have you tried that...

$db->query('your query');

Not sure if all the methods are on website, looks a bit sparse. Project looks great though.

Paul